# How To Ensure Vbscript Keeps Focus When Using Popup

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying without success to implement an unmodified  Microsoft scriptas I would like to use it in a script I intend to work on - (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee156593(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN     Reference = Listing 3.32 Displaying Timed Progress Message Boxes). However, when I run that script exactly as presented on the page the first popup message appears OK then disappears as required but the two subsequent messages, although they are generated OK, they do not come to the forefront but remain in the background behind whatever else is on the page at that time.
Listing 3.32 Displaying Timed Progress Message:

```` your text```Const TIMEOUT = 5 ```` your text`Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` your text`objShell.Popup "Disk Report Complete", TIMEOUT` your text`objShell.Popup "Memory Report Complete", TIMEOUT` your text``objShell.Popup "CPU Report Complete", TIMEOUT`

Can someone please run this same script off the page to see if they are getting the same result as I do. I have tried using vbSystemModal but it does not appear to be appropriate. The forum postings did not help me. If anyone can provide a solution as to why this script should not work properly I would be grateful.

Comment: AppActivate may help. Maybe a notification would work better. I'll take a look.

Comment: I tried AppActivate but was stumped for the application name as Desktop or vbscript didn't work. Thank you for your interest

Comment: I think I've solved it now. Vbscript was opening PopUp in a minimised page. By using Sendkeys to open the page maximised it seems to work properly. 

Const TIMEOUT = 5
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.SendKeys "% x"
objShell.Popup "Disk Report Complete", TIMEOUT
objShell.Popup "Memory Report Complete", TIMEOUT
objShell.Popup "CPU Report Complete", TIMEOUT

However, I am led to understand that SendKeys should only be used when all else has failed so if anyone has an alternative solution I would be glad to have it.

Comment: The `SendKeys "% x"` is likely to maximize the wrong window if you're using the computer. See my answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring a notice to the front reliably if you make it system modal:

**MsgBox**

```
MsgBox "Disk Report Complete",vbInformation+vbSystemModal,"Notice"
```

**PopUp**

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWSH.Popup "Disk Report Complete",5,"Notice",vbInformation+vbSystemModal
```

But I think a better option is to use the built-in notification system:

**Toast-Example.vbs**

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MyFolder = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
oWSH.CurrentDirectory = MyFolder

Sub Toast(Msg,Wait)
  oWSH.Run "Powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\Toast.ps1 """ & Msg & """",0,False
  WScript.Sleep Wait * 1000
End Sub

Toast "Disk Report Complete",7
Toast "Memory Report Complete",7
Toast "CPU Report Complete",7
```

**Toast.ps1** [adapted from here](https://den.dev/blog/powershell-windows-notification/)

```
Param (
  $Msg = ''
)

function Show-Notification {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]
        $ToastTitle,
        [string]
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $ToastText
    )

    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
    $Template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText02)

    $RawXml = [xml] $Template.GetXml()
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "1"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastTitle)) > $null
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "2"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastText)) > $null

    $SerializedXml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $SerializedXml.LoadXml($RawXml.OuterXml)

    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($SerializedXml)
    $Toast.Tag = "My Notices"
    $Toast.Group = "My Notices"
    $Toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddMinutes(1)

    $Notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("My Notices")
    $Notifier.Show($Toast);
}

Show-Notification $Msg
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in thanking you for your esteemed support once again. I have been on on extended holiday. I did try vbSystemModal but it wouldn't work. I haven't retained the lines of code I tried but I suspect that I had incorrect spelling in there somewhere. I was very impressed with your toast example and have studied it so I can learn from it. Eventually I will fully understand it!  Many thanks again!